# 違うgitのURLにプロダクトをpushしたい

Tags: git

違うgitのURLにプロダクトをpushしたいです。
~/Downloads/app/ git remote add origin https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git とコマンドを打つと、
fatal: remote origin already exists.　とエラーが出ました。
git clone https://github.com/myname/app.git と違うURLからプロダクトをダウンロードしてきたので、そのアドレスが設定されているのだとは思いましたが、https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git　のアドレスにpushするにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？ブランチを切り替える訳でもないし・・・。

Answer (score 3):

先にcloneした`myname/app.git`が既に`origin`として登録されているのであれば、違うgitのリモートリポジトリ=`myname/app_comp.git`はorigin以外の**別名**で登録する必要があります。

以下の例では`origin`の代わりに`mirror`としてリモートリポジトリを追加する実行方法です。

```
$ git remote add mirror https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git
```

もしくは既存の`origin`をいったん別名にリネームして、`myname/app_comp.git`を`origin`として登録し直すのもひとつの方法だと思います。

複数のリモートリポジトリを登録した場合には、`git remote`で確認すると以下の様な表示になります。

```
$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/myname/app.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/myname/app.git (push)
mirror https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git (fetch)
mirror https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0):

タイトルが「違うgitのURLにプロダクトをpushしたい」ということなので単純に以下の方法でも可能です。
※pushしようとしているブランチが何か不明なので仮にmasterとしています。

```
git push https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git master
```

---

質問内容や別の方の回答にあるように
`origin`は`https://github.com/myname/app.git`の別名として登録されています。
`git push`のコマンドでは以下のようにプッシュ先のリモートリポジトリを指定します。

```
git push <リモートリポジトリ> <プッシュするブランチ/コミットハッシュ>
```

ですので`mirror`として`https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git`を登録されるのであれば

```
git push mirror master
```

のようにコマンドを実行する必要があります。
`<プッシュするブランチ/コミットハッシュ>`は省略可能ですが、個人的に **「どこ」** に **「どんな変更」** をプッシュしようとしているのかを意識した方が良いと思うので、省略しない方が好みです。

Answer (score 0):

originを別のURLにしたいのであれば、

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myname/app_comp.git
```

で書き換えられます。その後、

```
git remote -v
```

でoriginのURLが書き換えられているのが確認できると思います。